# How to remove Unwanted lines from eclipse code file at one shot in mac

Tags: eclipse, whitespace

How to remove extra lines from eclipse code file at one shot in mac.

Example: Below java file has extra white lines- I want to remove all such lines in 1 shot.

`   JsonPath js = getOrderId.jsonPath();

```
String orderId = js.get("data.order.orderId");

Response deleteOrderResponse = 
            
given().spec(request()).delete(conf.deleteOrderEndPoint+orderId);
```

if (deleteOrderResponse.statusCode()==200) {

System.out.println(i+1+".OrderNumber : "+conf.orders+" Deleted successfully");

System.out.println("==============================================================");

if (response.statusCode()!=200) {

String s= "OrderNumber:"+conf.orders.get(i)+"Response Code=>"+response.statusCode()+"\n Error
message:"+js.get("errors[0].message");

}

Answer (score 0):

1. Open eclipse
2. open find/replace dialog box [command+f]
3. select the scope as per your choice [all/ selected line]
4. select "regular expression" in the options
5. now enter ^\s*\n as it is in the search box and click on replace all.

All line spacing will be removed.